# Python for loop in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

Good day, guys!
Be carefule of the COVID19 and solve 1 problem plz.

**I really want to get the address through crawling below with the value of column B and put it in column F.** → This is problem what I got

here's my source.
(This is the source for making simple dataframes.)

```
Start_Page = 0
End_Page = 500

for i in range(Start_Page, End_Page):
    page = i + 1
    url = "http://www.example.com &start=" + str(page)
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    json_str = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    json_object = json.loads(json_str)
    Mark = pd.json_normalize(json_object['jobs']['job'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(Mark)
    df = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
```

column's name is A to E.

**I really want to get the address through crawling below with the value of column B and put it in column F.**

(This is the source for crawling.)

```
B = B     # B in dataframe 'df'
result = urlopen("http://www.example2.com" + B)
html = result.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

address = str(soup.select_one("address.txt_address > span"))
address = re.sub('<.+?>', '', address, 0).strip()
```

```
B = B2 → append address to F2
...
...
...
B = B110000 → append address to F110000
```

How do I create a 'for loop' that adds the address to column F by using the value of B as a variable?
(I've been looking for a way for a week, but it was too difficult to find.)

Comment: Is your first df being populated? Can you include `df.B.head()` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question right,

but if your trying to get some address using the values from

'B' column and save it to a new 'F' column,

you could just select 'B' column and put it in a `for` loop.

```
values_for_f = []
for i in df['b'].values:
    result = urlopen("http://www.example2.com" + i)
    ....
    address = re.sub('<.+?>', '', address, 0).strip()
    values_for_f.append(address)
df['f'] = values_for_f
```